# passing my variable as parameter to MS Access function

Tags: ms-access, parameters

Is it possible to pass only the values of my variables into a pre existing method in Access?
For example the outputTo command looks like this

```
DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "rptName", acFormatSNP, strAttachmentPath
```

the strAttachmentPath works fine, I have this declared as strAttachmentPath = "C:...)

It's only a problem when I use a variable to declare the format like so:

```
DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "rptName", varFormat, strAttachmentPath
```

when I declare varFormat = "acFormatSNP" I get an error 'Compile error: Invalid Qualifier'.

Why is this not working?

The reason I want this is to be able to check which version of access is running. If it's 2003 use acFormatSNP, if it's any other use acFormatPDF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the content of acFormatSNP, it is a built in constant, so:

```
Dim stype as Text
stype = "Snapshot Format (*.snp)"
''Or, no quotes
stype = acFormatSNP 
DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "table1", stype, "z:\docs\test.snp"
```

Comment: When I do stype = acFormatPDF in access 2003 it won't compile since the acFormatPDF was introduced in version 2007 >. Is there a way around this? This is the reason I'm declaring the formats as separate variables.

Comment: It seems like I prematurely shot my wad! I used the if version = 2003 then use "snapshot Format(*.snp)" else use "PDF Format(*.pdf)". works great. thank you!